# Expected Identifier in C Stack using Linkedlist

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am facing several errors when trying to compile my code. My code represents a stack using LinkedList and Pointers. The errors is marked as a comment. I skipped several methods, because the error occurs in method "Creating new element"

This is the error:

```
In function ‘new_item’:
framework_stack.c:36:9: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘->’ token
     item->info = value;
     ^
framework_stack.c:37:9: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘->’ token
 item->ptr = NULL;
     ^
```

And the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node  
{
    int info;
    struct node *ptr;
}*top,*top1,*temp;

typedef struct node item;

item *top = NULL;

// my methods
void push(item *elem);
void *pop();
void empty();
void create();

int count = 0;

void create()
{
  top = NULL;
}

/* Creating new element */
item* new_item(int value) 
{ 
    item *temp = malloc(sizeof(item));
    item->info = value; // HERE IS THE ERROR
    item->ptr = NULL;  // HERE IS THE ERROR
}

void push(item *elem)
{
    if (top == NULL)
    {  
        top = elem;
    }
    else
    {
        top->ptr = elem;
        top = elem;
    }
    count++;
    item* head = NULL;
```

Comment: `item->info` should be `temp->info`, and `item* top` is declared twice

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. Where is item*top declared twice? I only used item* top one time

Comment: Once right after the `struct node` definition, and once in `item *top = NULL;`

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item` is a type, not a variable.

Use

```
  temp->info = value;
```